# Cron job script termination

Tags: cron

hey guys I am writing a cron job where I am executing a script like this, 
    0 8 * * * /home/User/ABC/all_messages.sh
So usually when I run script manually I do ctrl + C to stop the script, how do I do this in cron job? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to stop this manually is following:

1. Find the PID of the process.

   ```
   ps aux | grep /home/User/ABC/all_messages.sh
   ```
2. You will get an output like the following:

   ```
   agamaga+  40719  0.0  0.0  23756   940 pts/22   S+   15:39   0:00 /home/User/ABC/all_messages.sh
   ```
3. Here the second column is the PID, i.e. 40719 for this example.
4. Kill the process using the following.

   ```
   kill -9 <PID>
   ```

   i.e.

   ```
   kill -9 40719
   ```

This should terminate the process in question.

Another way is to terminate the process using its name (Although I don't prefer this one).

```
pkill /home/User/ABC/all_messages.sh
```